# Is the following array really multidimensional?

Tags: c#, arrays

Book I’ learning from claims that `intArray` has two dimensions. But since calling `intArray.GetLength(1)` will result in an `IndexoutOfRange` exception, couldn’t we claim that unlike rectangular arrays, `intArray` isn’t really multidimensional and thus has only one dimension?

```
int[][] intArray=new int[3][];
```

thank you

EDIT: BTW - I understand the difference between rectangular and jagged arrays

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does not have 2 dimensions. The syntax would be `int[,] intArray;`. This is a jagged array (an array that contains arrays. It's not square. For example, it might contain an array of size 2 and one of size 5.

Comment: I understand the difference between rectangular and jagged arrays, I'm just saying that my book refers to it as multidimensional

Comment: @flockofcode: Does the first sentence not answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

It's an array-of-arrays, or a jagged array. MSDN has an [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2s05feca.aspx) explaining what they are, and how they're different.

Most notably, a true 2D array is always rectangular - i.e. every row has the same number of columns. A jagged array may not even have a "row" (i.e. another array) at a given index - if it's `null` - or it may have "rows" of varying length.

Answer (score 0):

That is a jagged array
For a 2 dimensional array on which you can use getlength(1) see below

```
 int[,] intarray=new int[3,0];
 Console.WriteLine(intarray.GetLength(1));
```